# Select two 1 hour (HH:MM) string values with regular expressions

Tags: powershell, regex

I have the string or text data:

```
[string]$hours = @"


10/10/2022  
08:11
14:34
06:23   00:00   
11/10/2022  
08:05
14:28
06:23   00:00   
12/10/2022  
-
-
00:00   00:00   Día Festivo
13/10/2022  
08:10
18:47
10:37   -00:30  
14/10/2022  
07:28
-
00:00   00:00   
-
-

"@
```

How could I select the two consecutive `HH:MM` time values separated by a tab including the second optionally being a negative `-HH:MM` value?

**Expected Output:**

```
06:23
06:23
00:00
10:37
```

I only need it to select the ones that have double digits separated by a tab like the below values but only show the first time value set.

```
06:23   00:00   
06:23   00:00   
00:00   00:00
10:37   -00:30
```

I have the following code I've tried but I cannot get it to give me what I am after here.

```
$hour = $hours.split("`n").ToUpper() | Select-String  "" -AllMatches | ForEach {$_.Matches.value}
```

Comment: Are you even learning from all the powershell questions you ask? How is it you always use the same code for different problems? I am now doubting that you even try.

Comment: in this profession every minute that passes is learned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This PowerShell logic variation will omit [`-notmatch`] line matches that contain any upper or lower case letter (`"[a-zA-Z]"`).

It'll include [`-match`] any line match that starts with two digits (`^\d{2}`), a colon (`:`), followed by two more digits (`\d{2}`), followed by three white spaces (`\s{3,}`), an optional hyphen character (`-?`), followed by two digits (`\d{2}`), a colon (`:`), then two more digits (`\d{2}`)—this gives you the side-by-side `HH:MM` values in an array.

Lastly, it will then split those line results by the default space, and only output the first index value which will be the time values want (`$_.Split()[0]`).

### PowerShell (more specific based on example data)

```
$hours.Split("`n") | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch "[a-zA-Z]" -and $_ -match "^\d{2}:\d{2}\s{3,}-?\d{2}:\d{2}"} | ForEach-Object {$_.Split()[0]};
```

---

#### PowerShell (short form—more specific)

```
$hours.Split("`n") | ? {
    $_ -notmatch "[a-zA-Z]" -and 
    $_ -match "^\d{2}:\d{2}\s{3,}-?\d{2}:\d{2}" } | % {
    $_.Split()[0]
    };
```

---

#### PowerShell (another variation)

**Note:** *This match selects only the lines with two digits, followed by three spaces, followed by any negative or positive two digit number since you asked for this specifically too.*

```
$hours.Split("`n") | ? {
    $_ -notmatch "[a-zA-Z]" -and 
    $_ -match "\d{2}\s{3,}-?\d{2}" } | % {
    $_.Split()[0]
    };
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [Split()](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html)

  > **Key**
  >
  > `strSeparator`  The character used to split up each string, by
  > default whitespace (space/newline/tab)
- [Create and use PowerShell Arrays](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-arrays.html)

  > To retrieve an element, specify its number, PowerShell automatically
  > numbers the array elements starting at 0.
  >
  > So for example, this array:
  >
  > ```
  > PS C:\> $myArray = 64,"Hello",3.5,"World", "Demo"
  > ```
  >
  > Will have the automatic index numbers:
  >
  > ```
  > +----+-------+-----+-------+------+
  > | 0  |   1   |  2  |   3   |  4   |
  > +----+-------+-----+-------+------+
  > | 64 | Hello | 3.5 | World | Demo |
  > +----+-------+-----+-------+------+
  > ```
  >
  > Think of the index number as being an offset from the staring element.
  >
  > Return all the elements in an array:
  >
  > ```
  > PS C:\> $myArray
  > ```
  >
  > Return the first element in an array:
  >
  > ```
  > PS C:\> $myArray[0]
  > 64
  > ```
- [Where-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.1)
- [Regular Expressions](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-regex.html)
- [Regex to match 2 digits colon 2 digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686597/regex-to-match-2-digits-colon-2-digits)
- [How do I include negative decimal numbers in this regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814592/how-do-i-include-negative-decimal-numbers-in-this-regular-expression)
- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)

Comment: how could they be added?